# how to get callback while executing thread like paging

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm using thread and thread pool. Thread starts the execution and while executing, it one submit the task to the thread pool.Thread from thread pool retrieving data in large amount so I want that data like paging concept. how can I achieve it ?

I have implemented Callback like below program.

```
public class TestAsync implements TaskCallBack {
    public static ExecutorService exService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
        Task t1 = new Task();
        t1.doTask(new TestAsync());

    }

    public static ExecutorService getPool(){
        return exService;
    }

    @Override
    public void taskCompleted(String obj) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class Task {
 public void doTask(TaskCallBack tcb) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
     FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<>(new Task1());
     TestAsync.getPool().execute(ft);
     tcb.taskCompleted(ft.get());
 }

}

class Task1 implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());   
        /*
               Here code for data retrieval

        */

        return "done";
    }

  interface TaskCallBack{
      public void taskCompleted(String obj);
  }

}
```

In above program I'm waiting for entire  execution. I don't wan't that.

Answer (score 1):

You should not wait for the `get()` invocation to complete. If you do that you are blocking the caller thread.

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()):

> Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

Instead, something along the lines of this might work for you:

```
class Task1 implements Callable<String> {
    private final TaskCallBack callback;

    // Pass the callback to the task
    public Task1(TaskCallBack callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        /* Here code for data retrieval */

        // When the task has completed, return the result via the callback.
        // This will not be in the caller thread - it will instead be async
        callback.taskCompleted(result);

        return "done";
    }
}
```

And, to initialize it (and invoke it):

```
FutureTask<String> ft = new FutureTask<>(new Task1(myCallback));
TestAsync.getPool().execute(ft);
```

Comment: @VishveshPhadnis, if this helped feel free to Accept (the green tick) the answer so that the question gets closed properly!